# can't pass bitmap through intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-bitmap

[image]I am not able to pass image to another activity as bitmap

Main activity

```
Intent intent=new Intent(LastActivityGrid.this,ActivityMetadata.class);
byte[] image = Utils.getImageBytes(gridlist.get(position).getBitmap());
intent.putExtra("image",image);
startActivity(intent);
```

second activity

```
byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray,0,byteArray.length);
```

Comment: There is a limit of approximately 1 mb of data in the intent...

Comment: if possible pass the uri or location and reconstruct the bitmap from file

Comment: For sending an image to another intent the best thing is to store that image to SDcard and get that image from other intent. It is most reliable approach to send image to other Activities.

Comment: this might help http://www.jayrambhia.com/blog/pass-activity-bitmap

Comment: then how to reduce the size even i am converting it through utills getimagebytes

Comment: i have my final year project and i have only one thing remaining that one to pass gridview selected bitmap to next activity image view..

Comment: Please explain **in detail** what "I am not able to pass image to another activity as bitmap" means. What are your symptoms? Are you crashing? If so, what does the Java stack trace in LogCat tell you?

Comment: i stored images in database and showed that in grid view..now i want to move selected bitmap to next activity image view....

Comment: the code recived bitmap also convert to byte array but cant pass it through extra

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap implements Parcelable, so you could always pass it with the intent:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(LastActivityGrid.this,ActivityMetadata.class);
Bitmap image = gridlist.get(position).getBitmap();
intent.putExtra("image",image);
startActivity(intent);
```

and retrieve it on the other end:

```
Intent intent = getIntent(); 
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("image");
```

If Image is not too bit then It will work.

But proper solution is to pass the actual location of the image and get the Image from there in the second activity. But As I understand you prefer quick solution.

I hope it will help!

Comment: unable to pass to next activity...m trying from 2 days..but cant pass that bitmap ..i think put extra didn't catch the array..or may be i have no idea about size..

Comment: Could you please post the second activity code after the update of my answer, the code which I pasted is a working code. And I believe you have given enough details in my answer this line Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("image");

Comment: i have only problem in extra..bec my code can receive bitmap also convert to byte array..but can't pass to next activity

Comment: You should put exception any if it's printing in logcat.

Comment: i have updated the pic can u see and tell me whats the problem in that

Comment: Image doesnt give any information. As i belive it says Not Connected. Could you please post the code for ActivityMetadata.class , onCreate Method

Comment: @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_metadata);
         Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("image");
        // String stringVariableName = extras.getString("StringVariableName");
       // final int intVariableName = Integer.parseInt(stringVariableName);
        mydb = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewmetadata);
       imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: what is the resolution of the image?

Comment: 1080*1440..but don't after converting to blob for database it effects the resolution..

Comment: Since u storing in db why do u want to pass via intent? the image seems to be very big. Or to check our code is working properly or not just try to pass small image.

Comment: bec on which position i click the image move to next activity image view and there i will updete data for that pic in db..

Comment: Sorry difficult to understand what u said. I would suggest to read from dabatase.  The same way which u have done in previous activity, I don't think which will impact any of the functionality u have mentioned

Comment: my second activity catches the position id as u can see the pic but can not catch the image..any way thanks for ur time..